# Is there a way to log changes in the ".git" directory?

Tags: git, tags, branch, metadata, git-branch

For example, one person makes a branch (or a lightweight tag) and pushes the branch to the server. Seen from the local `.git` directory, some files were changes by a person. That person also is the one pushing. The server knows who does it because it needs to check the permission. Does git on the server get this information with who did that operation?

If I could do:

```
git log .git/refs/tags/tag
```

I could find out who created that tag.

If there would be a way to do this, one could answer questions like:

- who created/delete this branch
- who created/deleted this tag
- etc.

Or it there another way to find out authors of a git repo metadata changes?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a [`post-receive` hook](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html) in your server repository which would log what refs were updated, and how, and who did that.

As to *who* — this is somewhat tricky part as it wholly depends on which software actually did the authentication and authorization (and finally called the server-side Git process).  For instance, with [`gitolite` hooks](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/cust.html#hooks) the actual authenticated user name seems to be available in the `GL_USER` environment variable.  A `HTTP` server should export the `REMOTE_USER` environment variable etc.